# Why does NodeJS client continuously keep on disconnecting to RabbitMQ broker?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, keep-alive, messagebroker

I have installed RabbitMQ broker on Windows Server 2016. I have to connect to it using NodeJS client but it continuously disconnects and again connect to the broker. Can you please suggest what might have gone wrong ? I have gone through many articles but nothing solved my issue.

In order to achieve this,I have mentioned tcp keep-alive in rabbitmq.config file but it didn't solve my issue.

My configuration file looks like following :
rabbitmq.config (Location : C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\RabbitMQ)

```
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1883
## Default MQTT with TLS port is 8883
# mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 8883

# anonymous connections, if allowed, will use the default
# credentials specified here
mqtt.allow_anonymous  = true
mqtt.default_user     = test
mqtt.default_pass     = test

mqtt.vhost            = dev
mqtt.exchange         = amq.topic
# 24 hours by default
mqtt.subscription_ttl = 86400000
mqtt.prefetch         = 10

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=60
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=20
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3

handshake_timeout = 60000
```

Ideally client should connect to the broker only once and keep on listening on a port from that broker. It should never disconnect in between.

After making some changes in config file I always stop rabbitmq and again starts by using following commands from sbin directory of RabbitMQ :

```
rabbitmq-service.bat stop
rabbitmq-service.bat install
rabbitmq-service.bat start
```

When I hit 2nd command, I get error that the configuration file should be in Erlang format with '.conf' extension. I did that as well but I faced same issue again.

Is there anything missing in configuration ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that clients are sensitive, if you try to acknowlage the same message twice, for example, they will disconnect. Are you doing anything at all after you connect to the broker? Setting up queues that already exist with different params, declaring exchanges?